# IOS ipad 64 bit emulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios8

I am trying to test my ios app. it is an ipad only app, and I dont know how to test it for 64 bit compatibility, I cannot find an emulator ( for ipads ) that is 64bit.
Do I have to by a physical ipad air 2 to test it ?

Comment: Select a 64-bit OS in the emulator. Anything starting with iPhone 5S would run 64 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Resizable iPad" and "iPad Air" simulators run 64 bit architecture.